# react fullcalendar, collapsible events in resources

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar

is there any way to make event under resource to be collapsible? Like I have a parent event and its childs, I want its childs to be in dropdown menu under parent event, like I already have resources and events under them, but each event also can be collapsible and has some events in it

resource and parent event:

[image]

```
<Grid item md={10}>
            {timeFrames && (
              <FullCalendar
                eventDrop={handleResizeOrRedropEvent}
                eventResize={handleResizeOrRedropEvent}
                droppable={true}
                eventReceive={handleEventReceive}
                viewDidMount={handleViewChange}
                ref={refCalendar as LegacyRef<FullCalendar> | undefined}
                nowIndicator
                dayMaxEvents
                height="80vh"
                datesSet={(arg) => setCurrentDate(arg)}
                displayEventTime={false}
                eventClick={handleEventClick}
                eventsSet={handleEvents}
                weekends={true}
                editable={true}
                selectable={true}
                // selectMirror={true}
                plugins={[resourceTimelinePlugin, interactionPlugin]}
                events={[dragEventRow, ...timeFrames]}
                resources={[dragEventRow, ...timeFrames].map((timeframe) => ({
                  id: `${timeframe.type}-${timeframe.title}`,
                  title: timeframe.title,
                  type: timeframe.type,
                }))}
                resourceGroupField="type"
                resourceAreaWidth={'20%'}
                initialView="resourceTimeline"
                eventContent={renderEventContent}
                headerToolbar={{
                  left: 'prev,next today',
                  center: 'title',
                  right:
                    'resourceTimelineDay,resourceTimelineWeek,resourceTimelineMonth',
                }}
              />
            )}
          </Grid>
```

Tried to search any info about it, but found only questions/solutions about resources and collapsing them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the answer contains [in this repo](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-workspace/blob/main/premium/bundle/examples/resource-grouping.html), just need to add children to event like i did while receiving my events from API

```
 return promotionsAndChallenges
.map((entity) => ({
  ...entity,

  children: promotionsAndChallenges.filter(
    (child) => child.parent_id === entity.id
  ),
}))
.filter((entity) => !entity.parent_id);
```

and the resources prop in my Calendar component:

```
  <FullCalendar
            events={[dragEventRow, ...timeFrames]}
            resources={[dragEventRow, ...timeFrames].map((timeframe) => ({
              id: `${timeframe.type}-${timeframe.title}`,
              title: timeframe.title,
              type: timeframe.type,
              ...('children' in timeframe && {
                children: timeframe.children,
              }),
            }))}
            resourceGroupField="type"
 ...otherProps />
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable, and/or provide a code example which is relevant to the scenario in the original question. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers). See also [answer]. Thanks.

Comment: @ADyson thank you for the clarification, is it okay now?

Comment: Yes that's better, thanks